# Trouble running eclipse on Fedora 9, KDE 4.2 (Runs fine in Gnome)

Tags: linux, eclipse, fedora, kde-plasma

I recently installed KDE4.2 on my Fedora 9 machine, which already had Gnome, and have been trying to run Eclipse 3.3 (Europa, which ships with a Fedora Distro), but without luck. Eclipse runs fine when I use gnome session, however I need to use it in KDE.

I am attaching the screen-shot taken after the crash and some information about my machine:

> uname -a yields:
>
> Linux localhost.localdomain
>   2.6.25-14.fc9.i686 #1 SMP Thu May 1 06:28:41 EDT 2008 i686 i686 i386
>   GNU/Linux

I have a Intel Core 2 Duo processor. Also I have a host of JREs & JDKs ( JRE, JDK 5 and 6, JRE 4). JDK6 s the one in use.

I have a feeling that its something to do with gtk and qt. Since KDE runs on qt, I may need some plug-in. But couldn't find much upon searching the internet.

Some pointers would really help! Also, let me know if you need more information about the machine or eclipse

EDIT: Added the screenshot.

[image: Here is the image:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to download Eclipse from its site.

In my experence Linux distros are usually trying to be too smart with java apps, and I allways had better luck going to the source (Sun for JDK, Eclipse for the Eclipse).

Comment: This did the trick.. Strange though.. I always thought Linux distros provided reliable packages~

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse uses SWT library (SWT uses gtk++ on linux). I think your problem is somehow related to SWT library running in KDE environment not finding gtk++ library. But this is just guess.

Comment: SWT uses plain gtk2 or gtk3, not the C++ versions.

Answer (score 0):

Just saw the screenshot, try Sun JDK instead of openjdk.

Answer (score 0):

I had also bad experiences with the packaged Eclipse from the distributors. They often patch Eclipse to have the plugins in the system and leave only the application in the users home. This gave me often problems with plugins because of the missing rights.
Better to get a original Eclipse and place it in your home.

Mmh, you have the newest JRE installed (Sun JRE 6) so I cannot see a problem here. But you could remove the JRE package completely and reinstall it.

Comment: The main problem was the Aptana Studio Extension I had installed. It created a problem with Eclipse 3.2. I read through their forums and found out that installing eclipse 3.4 helps solve the problem And it did.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have gcj installed? I think Eclipse still uses gcj, and doesn't work with OpenJDK. When I last used Eclipse in Fedora (KDE 4.1.8x and Fedora 10), it ran fine.